# 17.04 wont see raid0 boot drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, raid

I fear I'm about to be flamed over this but I'm new to Linux and I would greatly appreciate some help.

I have a Z270g board running 2 x M2 drives in raid0 as a boot drive. Installing windows was straight forward but when I attempted to install 17.04 it wont see the raid at all.

It will boot and run fine from the USB drive but when I try to install there are no drive options to select. The disc utility only sees the USB.

I imagine that this is simply a driver issue but I have attempted every suggestion I could find on the net and I'm still at square one.
Grub2 will also not install which is frustrating because most suggestions I've seen involve this.

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is purely a newb related issue.. we all have to start somewhere right.

Answer (score 0):

installing grub is for getting an installed system to boot, this does not apply to you,

In your case it is one of two possibilities,

1) the installer doesn't have raid capability thus can't see it.

this I think is your most likely cause, since the installer doesn't report the drive. there is a way to get the raid support in the installer but I am not knowledgeable enough about the boot images to tell you how.

2) your USB is booting in a different mode than your windows install. (UEFI vs Legacy). the boot system of one can not read a drive partitioned for the other.

In this case the installer will usually see the disk but think it is unpartitioned. the fix is to get the USB to boot in the same mode as the windows install. the method depends on which way you need to go.

I know this isn't quite an answer but it is too big for a comment and hopefully helps guide you to the next step

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I knew that Grub was a bootloader but I thought that perhaps it was also somehow necessary to be running it. Strangely everything I've read suggests that this distro contains raid support.. I'm wondering if it's only a problem because my drives are M2 and not sata.

Comment: ah yes, I don't know what M2 is but would assume the controller is different thus requires a specific driver.

Comment: Cool. Good to know I'm more or less looking in the right direction. I actually just read a magazine article that was talking about the need for board drivers for M2 PCIe NVMe set ups like mine even without raid.